# Why can't C# 9 with expressions be used on interfaces

Tags: interface, record, c#-9.0

I would like to do the following (this doesn't compile):

```
public ITriggerModel UpdateDirtyTrigger(ITriggerModel dirtyTriggerModel)
{
    TriggerKey triggerKey = new(dirtyTriggerModel.Name, dirtyTriggerModel.Group);
    ITrigger trigger = _scheduler.GetTrigger(triggerKey);
    // Error: The reciever type "ITriggerModel" is not a valid record type.
    return dirtyTriggerModel with 
    {
        NextFireDateTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc(),
        PreviousFireDateTime = trigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc(),
        State = _scheduler.GetTriggerState(triggerKey),
    };
}
```

But the only way I managed to get it to work is with this horrible code duplication:

```
return dirtyTriggerModel switch
{
    DailyTriggerModel daily => daily with
    {
        NextFireDateTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc(),
        PreviousFireDateTime = trigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc(),
        State = _scheduler.GetTriggerState(triggerKey),
    },
    WeeklyTriggerModel week => week with
    {
        NextFireDateTime = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc(),
        PreviousFireDateTime = trigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc(),
        State = _scheduler.GetTriggerState(triggerKey),
    }
};
```

Comment: Because `with` expressions translate to a call to a protected unnamed Clone method and "copy constructor". You can't define either in your interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *with* expression works with record types.

`ITriggerModel` interface could be implemented by a class and `UpdateDirtyTrigger` could be called with an object of a class type (not a record type).